# Why does my Arduino IDE hang/crash so often?

Tags: arduino-ide, avr-gcc

I've traditionally used a text editor with avr-gcc and makefiles for working with Arduino boards. I'm now trying to develop projects for the wider Arduino user-base, so I am trying to use the Arduino libraries and common IDEs for ease of use.

I started using Stino, but then found out that the Arduino IDE has some toolchain "quirks" that mean I will need to test everything in Arduino IDE expressly.

Since starting to use it more, I have found it frequently hangs or crashes. The triggers for this are:

- Creating a new sketch takes about 15s, and shows me the OS X beach
  ball.
- Saving a sketch takes about 15s.
- Going to File->Examples frequently crashes the IDE - I need to force quit.
- Going to
  File->Sketchbook always crashes the IDE.
- It sometimes randomly hangs.

I don't have any other stability issues and other Java based IDEs like Pycharm work flawlessly.

I have installed numerous libraries, including the entire Teensyduino suite (which is a lot of libraries!). Outside of that, no changes have been made.

Is this a common issue? Is there any logging or anyway I can try and work out what is causing this issue?

This is happening with:
 - Arduino 1.05
 - Arduino 1.55

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I think the best way to report and have this issues fixed is by opening an issue on arduino's github https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues

Comment: I find it's sometimes a little slow to startup on my Mac, but I don't remember seeing any hangs/crashes like you describe. Which version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Mavericks, latest update.

Comment: I've only been using the arduino software package on Mac for less than a year. I've never used it on windows. I've run it under ML and now mavericks. In that time I have never had the arduino IDE crash. I habitually leave it open for days only restarting (or open and run a new instance) as needed. Have you made any hardware mods to it as in added boards or any tweaking?

Comment: Are you using up much RAM? What are the specs of your computer?

Comment: It's a late 2013 Macbook Pro with 16GB. Mavericks always reports all RAM used, but memory pressure is low and I have headroom to run several VMs and much more complex IDEs.

Comment: Are you using the new version 1.5.6-r2? Many things are said to have been improved compared to the previous 1.0.5-r2 version. Given that I am on Win only, I cannot confirm those slow experiences.

Comment: Should this question be closed? This has all the makings of a bug, and we are not a bug tracking site.

Comment: It can be, but the question "Is there any logging or anyway I can try and work out what is causing this issue?" hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 1):

### Just [report it to Arduino](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues).

You don't really have any other option. I've been waiting to answer this question until I was sure that no one here knew the answer. You don't really have any other option.

This seems like a bug. **We're not Arduino developers or a bug tracking site.** We can only do so much here. Even if it was confirmed a bug and we fixed it, there's only so much that can be done without submitting a report.

---

**BEFORE YOU SUBMIT A REPORT:**

- I'd try copying out the libraries from Arduino. So many libraries
  might make Arduino IDE somewhat heavier. I don't know if it'll really
  affect the sluggishness but it's worth a shot.
- The only other thing that I can think of, besides RAM (which you
  already said wasn't an issue) and the libraries, is some sort of
  cache/temporary file. Try reinstalling Arduino, even if you haven't,
  and also I'd try using the [beta 1.5.6-r2
  version](http://arduino.cc/en/main/software). It has to be pretty
  stable for it to be the only version that supports the YUN and DUE.
  Both have been out for a considerable amount of time with this
  software, so I'd imagine that it's pretty stable minus a few issues.

> Many things are said to have been improved compared to the previous 1.0.5-r2 version.

It'd be stupid not to try the newer version.

[image: GitHub Screenshot]

Comment: I've just tried 1.5.6-r2 and the same issue exists (it wasn't listed as the beta on the downloads page when the question was initially asked). Nothing in the release notes suggests that any IDE changes have been made between 1.5.5 and 1.5.6-r2 though.

Comment: I guess the bigger part of the question is "Is there any logging?". Without any detail to go on, the bug report will be lost in the thousands of others.

Comment: @Cybergibbons Have you tried my other ideas? Temporarily removing the libraries?

Comment: Yes, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

For debug and logging you can use the Mac Console app, it will show any errors that come up from the App. You might need to filter for Arduino App related messages though.